# Упростить метод по булеву значению

Tags: c#, логика

мне необходимл присвоить данные двум переменным `Property1 & Property2`

total  находится в `CountTotal`

в зависимоти если `ValPerson` = 1 | 0

если 1 = то тотал идет в проперти1 если 0 то тотал идет в проперти2

*(там только 1 и 0 почему то инт, но мне объяснили я так и не поняла, вижу что инт принимаю, но вроде это булево значение, может я тип неправильный даю, я просто написала инт, а может есть по другому как bool дает ошибку, то есть я написала в модели bool, компилятор ругался но данные не показал, только написал что конверт не смог сделать моего джейсона, может я не знаю какой тип типа булИнт(?)...)*,
но в базе либо один либо ноль (но это отдельный вопрос по совместимости БД)

```
public class Weighs
{
    public int ValPerson { get; set; }
    public int CountTotal { get; set; }

    public int Property1 { get => @CalculForProperty1(ValPerson, CountTotal); }
    public int Property2 { get => @CalculForProperty2(ValPerson, CountTotal); }

    public int CalculForProperty1(int who, int nbCalcul1)
    {
        if (who != 0)
        {
            return nbCalcul1;
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    public int CalculForProperty2(int who, int nbCalcul2)
    {
        if (who == 0)
        {
            return nbCalcul2;
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

@aepot я подправила отталкиваясь от нуля

я как понимаю так и сделала, помогите исправить этот расчет, или верно расчитываю ?

и плюс два метода, как то упростить бы

Comment: Абстракция вопроса зашкаливает. Человеческими словами бы узнать, в чем смысл всего этого? Этот код не работает? Как вы это поняли? Покажите отладочную информацию.

Comment: @aepot ну вроде пишу человеческими словами, или языки у человек разные стали... отладочная информация это таблица в которую даю эти две переменные, там просто показывает то что передаю, график синфузион, там мало что требуется для моего ответа. мне нужно расчитать в зависимости от одной переменой = присвоить двум другим

Comment: Так работает этот код или не работает?

Comment: код работает расчет не могу понять верный или нет делаю

Comment: сравниваю с бд по моему что то не то расчитываю, точнее не так как нужно расчитываю

Comment: тег логика поэтому и добавила

Comment: Пока в понимании смысла `bool`  у вас пробел. `true` это не `0`, это может быть `1` или любое другое число. То есть проверять надо на `0` а не на `1`.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146338/discussion-between-dev18-and-aepot).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так можно этот код упростить.

```
public class Weighs
{
    public int ValPerson { get; set; }
    public int CountTotal { get; set; }

    public int Property1 => CalculForProperty(ValPerson != 0, CountTotal);
    public int Property2 => CalculForProperty(ValPerson == 0, CountTotal);

    private int CalculForProperty(bool who, int num)
    {
        return who ? num : 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: а логика верна ? то есть если не ноль, правильно понимаю что идет в проперти 1 и наоборот. по другому ведь не может быть?

Comment: @Dev18 как-то так, да